# Task state not updating when using custom state

Tags: python, celery

I have a task like this:

```
@task
def test():
    time.sleep(10)
    test.update_state(state="PROGRESS")
    time.sleep(10)
    return "done"
```

I then run this:

```
>>> from celery.execute import send_task
>>> t = send_task("testcelery.test")
>>> t.state
'PENDING'
>>> t.state
'PROGRESS'
```

I can see in the worker that the task has completed:

> [2011-02-19 20:18:43,851: INFO/MainProcess] Task testcelery.test[7598b170-2877-4d76-89a0-9bcc4c9f877e] succeeded in 20.0225799084s: 'done'

But t.state never changes from PROGRESS to SUCCESS. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should upgrade to Celery 2.2.4 (released yesterday) as it fixes the bug that causes this.

See http://celeryq.org/docs/changelog.html

Comment: 2.2.4 fixed it. Thank you ask!

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like CELERY_IGNORE_RESULT set would cause this behavior.  What is t.ignore_result?  If it is true then either change it or change the default.  If you want to always inspect the result then changing CELERY_IGNORE_RESULT makes more sense to me.  But then setting it on every task would make your intentions more obvious.

Comment: I think you mean test.ignore_result not t.ignore_result? I'm not setting ignore result, but just to double check, I checked the value of test.ignore_result during my task and it's False.